# How to realize `with` in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I just wanna make a simple template engine sample in coffeescript, but I came across an issue when I used `with` keyword in my code. Since `with` is a reserved word in coffeescript, is there anyway I could do to realize the same function just like `with` in native javascript? Thanks

Comment: No idea what you are asking. Can you provide some code samples?

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to use the `with`  keyword, unless you have a specific use case for it. See [this article](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html) for more information.

Comment: `with` is regarded as an anti-pattern. I never noticed coffeescript having it, so I bet they never implemented it. If you think you need it, then you are doing it wrong :P

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. At first, I just want to make my owner simple  template engine, just like ``<%= name%>`` with ``{name: 'test'}`` could be shown on the page as ``test``, so I need this ``with`` to compile the obj to the template. If there is no way to realize ``with`` in coffee script, then I think I have to figure out another way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't; `with` is not supported in CoffeeScript.